# C# Search "Did you mean" functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net, search

I want to implement a google "Did you mean" kind of a functionality with asp.net/c#.
User input "Red Sheos", and hit search,
Out put shows, "Did you mean 'Red Shoes'".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your'll need a spell checker and dictionary. I'll suggest you start with [NHunspell](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 3):

[My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9014045/regex-compare-two-strings-to-find-alliteration-and-assonance/9014069#9014069) (though on a somewhat different subject) should give you ideas on non-exact matches. Several good options available for dealing with how words "sound". I'd start with [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Taking a different approach, SQL Server Full Text indexing can also provide non-exact matching with minimal code. It's not necessarily intended for correction per se, but determining the user's intention isn't always about just phonetic similarity.

To achieve real-time performance (e.g. search as you type), consider a data structure as I describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623477/what-type-of-collection-should-i-use/8623535#8623535) (a trie, or a hybrid thereof).

Answer (score 3):

Check for Trie Data structure , see here [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Most of the spell checker implements some sort of Trie also if you need to implement auto complete feature then also you can think of Trie

see below code review stackexchange question

[Code Review trie](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/19802/is-this-a-valid-implementation-of-trie-data-structure/19815#19815)

Answer (score 1):

Try to get inspiration from an Autocorrect functionality. Basically what you would do is to call autocorrect on the entered text and if a "solution" is found, show that as the `did you mean` suggestion.

These might help:

[How do autocorrect algorithms work in PHP and/or C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854783/how-do-autocorrect-algorithms-work-in-php-and-or-c)

[AutoCorrect Text C# Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304013/autocorrect-text-c-sharp-word)